# Starting Pentaho BI Server as a windows service?

Tags: windows-services, pentaho

I am new to Pentaho BI , I am using 'Peantho BI community edition'. please guide me on how to starting BI Server as a windows service.
Currently, I am starting Pentaho server manually, however, I want to start BI server as a Windows service.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance,
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a product called YAJSW - Yet another java service wrapper.

very easy to use, i've used this both with Carte and BI Server.

If you check the pentaho wiki there's a guide to running Carte (DI server) using this wrapper, the instructions should be similar for BI server.